# Why is “truth” a trait of compassion?

Tags: parashat-ki-tisa, rabbeinu-tam, thirteen-attributes

One of the Thirteen Attributes of Mercy is that of “truth” (Shemos 34:6). ArtScroll (ex. Yom Kippur Machzor, p. 110) quotes Rabbeinu Tam,<sup>1</sup> who explains that “truth” refers to the fact that He never reneges on His promises; “His promise to reward the deserving will be carried out unequivocally.”

How is that a trait of kindness? That’s justice - He does what He says. Further, the promise is to reward “the deserving,” which is still justice - if they deserve it, they get it.

I am aware that there are other readings of the Thirteen Attributes; I ask specifically according to this explanation in the name of Rabbeinu Tam.

---

<sup>1</sup>They quote Rosh HaShanah 17b, which I assume refers to Rabbeinu Tam cited in Tosfos DH “shelosh esrei midos,” but I only see where he addresses the first few and the last few, not the ones in between, including the one in question here.